# How to use remote computers terminal with serial connection with xbee and PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, serial-port, putty

I am using two different laptops for my project. One is installed with Window and the other is installed with Ubuntu. My specific goal is to able to use Ubuntu terminal with Window computer with serial connection and without wireless internet. For my case, I used xbee device (This can replace my serial cable) for the both side of my laptops to run wireless remote serial communication.

For the first stage, if I say I have wifi connected to both of the computers, I could use PuTTY and SSH my IP from the Ubuntu and connect to the terminal with IP address. However, instead of using SSH, I tried using serial feature from the PuTTY. I turned on both of the serial ports with PuTTY.

[image: PuTTY image]

This is what I see. What I expected was to see terminal of Ubuntu computer. However, instead, I was just able to send and receive text from Ubuntu. Technically this can be done just by using XCTU (software supported for xbee device.) Is there any easy way for my Windows computer to access Ubuntu like I did it with SSH?